# Run after_update callback in background in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

I have defined a callback on a model with after_update, where mails should be sent to all users when the date changes.

Now I have noticed during a test that the controller with which the model is updated does not respond with any status until the ActionMailer has sent all mails.

How can I make this a background task? I have also tested the same with after_update_commit, but without success.

```html
class Meeting < ApplicationRecord  
  after_update :date_change_notification
```

```html
  def date_change_notification
      meetings = Meeting.where(:meeting_id => self.id)
      tickets.each do |ticket|
        user = ticket.user
        begin
          notification_status = UserNotificationSubscription.find_by(:users_id => user.id, :notification_types_id => 1)
          if notification_status.nil? || notification_status.subscribed
            UserMailer.meeting_date_changed(self, user).deliver
          end
        rescue StandardError => e
        end
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send the emails in a background job using `ActiveJob` just change

```
UserMailer.meeting_date_changed(self, user).deliver
```

to

```
UserMailer.meeting_date_changed(self, user).deliver_later
```